# Create program to take account number and returning account information in python

Tags: python, dataframe

The dataset has account information that I must analyze to confirm where the data comes in incorrectly.

I would like to create a program that takes an input and from the input show the account information that is within the dataset.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific bit of code that's not working? At the moment I think this question is way to broad to be answered. Maybe take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to index your dataframes:

```
data = {}
someAccount = # the account
data[someAccountNumber] = someAccount

while True:
    try:
        accountNumber = int(input("Enter account number to retrieve: "))
        break
    except:
        print("Please enter a valid account number.")

if accountNumber in data:
   print(data[accountNumber])
else:
   print("No account associated with this number was found.")
```